# What is the difference between the roots א-מ-ן and ב-ט-ח? Between Emunah and Bitachon?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, language, faith-bitachon-emunah

Both of the א-מ-ן and ב-ט-ח roots are used to imply some level of trust in G-d; i.e., faith in Him.

Bereshit 15:6 opens:

> "And he believed (aman) in the LORD"

2 Melachim 18:5:

> "He trusted (batach) in the LORD, the G-d of Israel"

What then is the difference between them? What is the difference between Emunah and Bitachon?

Answer (score 5):

This is a big question. One could write a book on the topic! (wait, the Chazon Ish [actually did](http://a.co/gaTyYPB), and [so did](http://a.co/ecxsIFU) R Avigdor Miller).

But in a simple way (taken from Ben Tzion Shafier [here](https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/difference-emunah-bitachon/)) emunah is the knowledge that Hashem created and continues to run all of Creation and that he is involved in the minutiae of my daily life.

Bitachon is acting on that knowledge and relying on/trusting Hashem. It is a sense of depending on Him to watch over and protect me.

Emunah is a state of understanding. Bitachon is a state of trust. Emunah comes from studying this world and seeing that there is a Creator. Bitachon is the state of trust that comes from recognizing that that Creator is good, kindly and wise—and that He cares deeply for His creations.

See also R Hershel Schachter [here](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2012/parsha/rsch_vayeshev.html)

> Bitachon requires that we act in accordance with our emunah, i.e. in
>   accordance with this principle of faith that there is hasgacha pratis.
>   While one must engage in hishtadlus, he should not fall to pieces
>   considering the possibility that he may accidentally (i.e. not in
>   accordance with the divine will) die, etc. The outcome of all
>   situations is dictated by the will of Hashem, and everything Hashem
>   does is ultimately l'tov.

Comment: mbloch, I once understood the opposite of bitachon is fear, while the opposite of emunah is doubt in order to show some difference. But then I saw Genesis 15:1 “Fear not Avraham..” was HaShem saying he should have bitachon, or emunah? What do you think?

Comment: I like this doubt/fear distinction - works quite well. I'd say Avraham had immense emuna, if anything God was telling him to have bitachon. Also, to ping someone, you need to add @ before their username (worked here because there is only one possible person to ping)

Comment: Two things I would add, but they're too big to just force in with an edit (impolite):
Going back to the roots, since that's how the question was asked... Both relate to trust, but they differ in the when of I am being trusting about. When I find a fact trustworthy, I am ma'amin that fact. It's about something already being true. When I find someone or Someone trustworthy, I have bitachon they will do things right, that something is bound to become true.

Comment: R' Meir Birnbaum (author of Pathway to Prayer booklets) told me, but I do not recall his source:

This is why Chazal tell you not to break between Ge'ulah (the last berakhah after Shema) and Tefillah. (Except for those in EY who at Maariv said the Amidah first, but that's whole different topic...) Ge'ulah is emunah about the past, belief in yetzi'as mitzrayim and other redemptions in our history. Tefillah relies on bitachon -- we wouldn't be making requests of G-d if we didn't think He can alter our future.

Answer (score -1):

when answering Amen you are saying true or confirmed Betach means trusting or hoping in hashem

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. A source for these assertions could greatly improve your answer. I hope you enjoy your time here, and see you around!

Comment: Hi Howi. This question isn't asking about the word "amen" but rather about the root א-מ-נ as in the Hebrew word אמונה